# How to extract the ids and keys using linux command?

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have list of ids matched with key values of second column, I want to remove the duplicates and retain the corresponding values as comma or colon separated as shown in the out put format
Input file

```
TRINITY_DN728479_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003674
TRINITY_DN728479_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003824
TRINITY_DN728479_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003887
TRINITY_DN728480_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003891
TRINITY_DN728480_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003892
```

I want the output

```
TRINITY_DN728479_c0_g1_i1        GO:0003674, GO:0003824, GO:0003887
TRINITY_DN728480_c0_g1_i1        GO:0003891,GO:0003892
```

I have tried awk but it not working out

```
awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 }' Gene.GO | sed 's/,$/\n/'
```

Comment: please show what you've tried

Comment: `I have tried awk but it not working out`, looks like you forgot to add your code, please do add that which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I know only convert the column in comma separated file with this command             awk -vORS=, '{ print $2 }' Gene.GO | sed 's/,$/\n/'

Comment: @MathavanMuthaiyan, There is nothing right or wrong with your efforts(tried code), feel free to add it in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: You never need to pipe awk to sed or vice-versa, a script that produces output without a terminating newline is bad as that is undefined behavior for the next tool (so don't assume you can add a newline later as you're trying to do with sed), and using `-vORS=` is un-necessarily gawk-only, put a space after `-v`, e.g. `-v ORS=`, so it'll work in all awks.

Answer (score 3):

If the input is 2 columns and already grouped by column 1

```
awk '
{
  printf "%s", ($1==p ? "," $2 : ors $0)
  ors = ORS
  p = $1
} END {printf "%s", ors}' file
```

Comment: Nice, especially the END section which will work correctly even for an empty input file.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. In case your 1st field is NOT sorted then use `sort` with `awk` code.

```
sort -t_ -k1 -k2 Input_file | 
awk '
  BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }
  prev!=$1 && prev{
    print prev,value
    value=""
  }
  {
    value=($1 in value ? value[$1] s1: "")$2
    prev=$1
  }
  END{
    if(prev && value){
      print prev,value
    }
  }
'
```

***2nd solution:*** Only `awk` solution, this will give you output in same order in which 1st field is coming in Input_file.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ s1=","; OFS="\t" }
!arr1[$1]++{
  arr2[++count]=$1
}
{
  value[$1]=($1 in value ? value[$1] s1: "")$2
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print arr2[i],value[arr2[i]]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***3rd solution:*** In case you are not worried of order of 1st field in output then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ s1=",";OFS="\t" }
{
  value[$1]=($1 in value ? value[$1] s1: "")$2
}
END{
  for(i in value){
    print i, value[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Your second script could be much clearer if you use variable names that tell you what they represent rather than how they're implemented, e.g. if you change `arr1` -> `seen`, `arr2` -> `keys`, and `count` -> `numKeys`.

Comment: @Mathavan Muthaiyan, could you please do let me know if my solution has worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

With [datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```sh
$ datamash -W -g1 collapse 2 <ip.txt 
TRINITY_DN728479_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003674,GO:0003824,GO:0003887
TRINITY_DN728480_c0_g1_i1   GO:0003891,GO:0003892
```

- `-W` use space/tab as field separator
- `-g1` group by column `1`
- `collapse 2` to collect all values in column `2` based on column `1` key

If input is not sorted, use `-s` option or pipe the input from `sort` command. Output field delimiter is tab here, you can change using `--output-delimiter` option.